# Accessing claims via the security principal attached to the request thread, versus AuthorizationContext

Tags: wcf, azure, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I'm working with the [Azure ACS Labs](http://acs.codeplex.com/documentation) where they are using [FederatedServiceCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.federatedservicecredentials.aspx) to authenticate users for Active Federation.  Now I want to access the claims of the user from within the WCF service.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd278426.aspx), the claims are accessed by the request thread... Can anyone explain or demonstrate what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request thread is the thread which is executing your service API on the server.  From that thread (aka within your service api), you can access Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.  This will be a ClaimsIdentity, which contains the claims granted to you by your STS.  For example:

```
 class MyService:IService
 {
   // code running on wcf server
   bool AdminOnlyApi()
   {    
     var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

     // fail all non admin callers.
     if (!identity.Claims.Exists(c=>c.ClaimType=="role" && c.Value=="Admin"))
     {
        throw new SecurityException("Access is denied.");
     }
     return True;
   }  
 }
```